# Reformat table - Number of digits

Tags: table

I have some tables were the numbers have too much digits; as follow:

```
MONTH A1 A2 A3  ......
1 1.54564468 2.48949 6.4984984 .....
```

Is there a way, using unix, to reformat the table in the following way:

```
MONTH A1 A2 A3 ...
1 1.54 2.49 6.50 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is actually a file of TAB-separated values:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR-1 { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = sprintf("%.2f", $i) } 1' <file.csv
```

**Edit:** Same thing with Perl:

```
perl -lape '$.-1 and $_ = join "\t", map { sprintf "%.2f", $_ } @F' file.csv
```

Comment: my input file is "space" delimited. How can I adapt your line of code?

Comment: You change `\t` to a space: `OFS=' '`, resp. `join " ", ...`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "using unix", but just about any tool that provides basic a C-style `(s)printf` function should be able to do that, for example at its simplest

```
$ perl -pe 's/\d+\.\d+/sprintf "%.2f", $&/ge'
MONTH A1 A2 A3  ......
1 1.54564468 2.48949 6.4984984 .....
MONTH A1 A2 A3  ......
1 1.55 2.49 6.50 .....
```

The exact command required will depend on the details of your table data - for example whether it needs to handle more general floating point numbers (possibly including exponents for example).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start:

`for line in "1 1.54564468 2.48949 6 .4984984"; do printf "%.2f " $line; done`

1.00 1.55 2.49 6.00 0.50